# The Refresh method for ListBox won't trigger the event handler for the DrawItem property

Tags: c#, forms, delegates, thread-safety, eventhandler

I'm trying to create a listBox that is bound to a list and when it checks, or performs certain process with each element of the list, it will change the color of that item on the listbox control.
The first time the listbox loads it displays all the elements from the list and goes through my listbox_Drawitem event handler that receives the DrawItemEventArgs event.
But when I want to refresh the listbox to redraw the items with the updated state or color, it never goes through the listbox_DrawItem event handler.

I tried using the refresh method by itself with no success.
I've tried setting the list.Datasource to null followed by list.refresh, which erases everyhting in the listbox, and then setting the data source again to my list and refreshing but nothing happens.

I'm working with two threads and  when I edit my controls from another thread other than my UI form, I do it through delegates to avoid cross thread errors. So far it had been working, except for the DrawItem handler that should get triggered with my control being redrawn by the refresh inside the safeRefreshAllMethod in my delegate.

This is the code from my UI form:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public delegate void SafeRefresh();
        public SafeRefresh myDelegate;
        private Form1 currentForm;
        Thread scriptThread;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            currentForm = this;
            myDelegate = new SafeRefresh(SafeRefreshAllMethod);

        }
        private async void button_script_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            scriptThread = new Thread( () => SomeClass.RunScript(currentForm));
            scriptThread.Start();
        }

        public void SafeRefreshAllMethod()
        {

            listBox.DataSource = null;
            listBox.Refresh();
            listBox.DataSource = Global.ListAllItems; 
            listBox.Refresh();
        }


        public void listBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            Brush myBrush;
            if (Global.ListItemsDisconnected.Contains(Global.ListAllItems[e.Index] ))
            {
                myBrush = Brushes.Gray;
            }
            else if (Global.ListItemsConnected.Contains(Global.ListAllItems[e.Index]))
            {
                myBrush = Brushes.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                myBrush = Brushes.Black;
            }

            e.DrawBackground();
            e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox.Items[e.Index].ToString(), listBox.Font, myBrush, e.Bounds);
        }

    }
```

and this is the code executed by the new thread in the form, which invokes the delegate for the refresh of the listbox control:

```
class SomeClass {
public static void  RunScript(Form1 theForm)
        {
            theForm.Invoke(theForm.myDelegate);

            foreach (string item in Global.ListAllItems)
            {

                //some code that works with the items on list
                //if disconnected : adds to Global.ListItemsDisconnected
                //if connected: adds it to Global.ListItemsConnected

                theForm.Invoke(theForm.myDelegate);


            }
        }
}
```

I would like to know if someone knows why the listBox_DrawItem, gets triggered when the thread invokes the control for the first time, drawing all items in the list. But when I try to refresh and redraw the list with different colors the handler never gets called.

Comment: Am not able to duplicate this. Each time I click the button the script runs fine and does call DrawItem. Can you explain more how you are trying to refresh and redraw

Comment: When I debug, I can see how the 'theForm.Invoke(theForm.myDelegate') process from the first statement in 'RunScript', invokes the 'SafeRefreshAllMethod' and afterwards the event handler ' listBox_DrawItem' is triggered. This draws the items in the listBox for the first time, but once the foreach loop is running and the same method gets invoked again, ' listBox_DrawItem' handler doesn't get triggered, so the items just disappear after setting the data source to null, but they never get redrawn after the refresh .

Comment: I saw it getting called when the delegate in invokes inside the foreach loop, drawItem event in invoked when we set the datasource on the line listBox1.DataSource = Global.ListAllItems;

Answer (score 0):

View the Designer and try to change **DrawMode** property to **OwnerDrawFixed**.

[ListBox DrawMode Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawmode?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I have tried it and it works fine on my environment. Maybe it's better if you add the Global class to your question so that we can reproduce the issue.@BLM